# Setting a Dynamic Audio Playlist

Tags: php, html, mp3, media-player

I'm using an HTML5 audio player (Speakker). I've created a function to dynamically create a playlist, but I'm not sure how to implement the playlist once I've created it. This seems like the sort of thing that someone with more experience might just take for granted. I hope that's the case.

Create the playlist. Check.

```
    <?php $playlist= "{\"playlist\": [";?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item){
        $titlemetadata= metadata($item, array('Dublin Core', 'Title'));
            foreach($item->Files as $file) {
                // print_r($file);
                $sourcemetadata= metadata($file, 'uri');
                $imagemetadata= metadata($file, 'thumbnail_uri');
                if (strpos($file["filename"], 'mp3') !== false) {
                    $playlist .=
                    "\"0\": {\"src\":\"$sourcemetadata\", \"type\":\"audio/mp3\"}, 
                    \"config\": 
                    {\"title\": \"$titlemetadata\",
                    \"poster\": \"$imagemetadata\"}";
                }
            }       
    }?>
    <?php $playlist .= "]}";?>
    <?php echo $playlist;?>
```

Implement the playlist? Nope.

`<audio class="projekktor speakker dark">
        <source src= ??THE PLAYLIST?? type="application/json"/>
    </audio>`

Comment: To clarify. The code in the speakker readme shows that the playlist is declared like so:
`<audio class="projekktor speakker dark">
    <source src="speakker-big-1.2.07r157/playlist.json" type="application/json"/></audio>`
I'd like to use a $playlist variable instead of a json file. The documentation says that I can set a playlist:
`projekktor('player_a').setFile(playlist);`
I'm not sure where to put the code, if it's compatible with php, or if it even still works given that the documentation states that it's outdated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked out. Here's a solution:

```
<?php $collections=get_records("collection", array("public"=>"true","featured"=>"true"));
  $current_collection=end($collections);
  $items=get_records("item", array("collection"=>$current_collection));

  $playlist= "[";
  foreach ($items as $item){
    $titlemetadata= metadata($item, array("Dublin Core", "Title"));
        foreach($item->Files as $file) {
            $sourcemetadata= metadata($file, "uri");
            $imagemetadata= metadata($file, "thumbnail_uri");
            if (strpos($file["filename"], "mp3") !== false) {
                $playlist .=
                "{\"0\": {\"src\":\"$sourcemetadata\", \"type\":\"audio/mp3\"}, 
                \"config\": 
                {\"title\": \"$titlemetadata\",
                \"poster\": \"$imagemetadata\"}},";
            }
        }       
   }
   $playlist .= "]";?>
<?php 
    $string = '$(document).ready(function() {projekktor(".projekktor").setFile(' . $playlist . ');});';
queue_js_string($string);?>
```